# How to use generic with SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, generics

I created a class called DB_Processor_Generic, which is used to create different database and do add/get data operations. But I need to use this class with different data types, so I consider using generic, but when I use the **"_db.Query()"** as shown below, I get the error saying that

> 'T' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless
> construction in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type
> or method 'SQLiteConnection.Query(string, params object[])

Is there anything wrong with my code? Cause I am new to this community, if there is anything wrong with my question discription, plz correct me thanks

```cs
    public class DB_Processor_Generic<T>
    {
        private SQLite.SQLiteConnection _db;
        private string _path;

        //Constructor
        public DB_Processor_Generic(string path)
        {
            _path = path;
            _db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(this._path);
            _db.CreateTable<T>();
        }

        //Method
        public void AddData<T>(T t1)
        {
            _db.Insert(t1);
        }

        public List<T> GetDB<T>(string tableName)
        {
            var DB_List = _db.Query<T>($"SELECT * FROM {tableName}");
            return DB_List;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error tells you you need to add a constraint to your T:

```
public class DB_Processor_Generic<T> where T : new()
```

because `Query<T>` has that constraint on T in it's definition, so yours must be set as well in order to use your T as it's type parameter.

Comment: To elaborate, if `Query` is going to return a list of objects of type `T` then it obviously needs to be able to create those objects, which it does by invoking the parameterless constructor of that type. You have to guarantee that any type specified for `T` at run time will have a parameterless constructor by applying that constraint. If you then try to specify a type that doesn't have a parameterless constructor, the compiler will flag it as invalid.

Comment: Thanks, should I write this statement like ```var DB_List = _db.Query<T>($"SELECT * FROM {tableName}") where T:new();```? but seems ```where``` keyword is not valid

Comment: @Jonesopolis I have tried change the code according to your suggestion, but the error still insists, I still have no idea about what's wrong

Comment: the `where T : new()` goes on the line you define `T`.  Here it is on your class.  Just copy my code above and replace your class definition